# Как заставить телеграмм бота отправить svg изображение https://phys-ege.sdamgia.ru/get_file?id=69140

Tags: python, telegram-bot, requests, beautiful-soup

Делаю телеграмм бота который отправляет задачи с сайта https://phys-ege.sdamgia.ru/
Нужно отправить Изображение.
Как я понимаю нужно конвертировать svg в png или jpeg, но при использовании библиотеки pyvips выдаёт ошибку

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/Питончик/hbntdfg.py", line 1, in <module> import pyvips File "C:\Users\denve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvips\__init__.py", line 70, in <module> gobject_lib = ffi.dlopen(_gobject_libname) File "C:\Users\denve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 150, in dlopen lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags) File "C:\Users\denve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags) File "C:\Users\denve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 828, in _load_backend_lib return backend.load_library(path, flags) OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll': error 0xc1`

Пытался исправить но безуспешно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.